# An isomorphism related to Fontaine's periods rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, galois-representations

Let $\Lambda$ be a ring, $V$ a $\Lambda$-algebra complete Hausdorff for the $p$-adic topology where $p$ a a prime integer. Assume that $V/pV$ is semiperfect (i.e., the Frobenius map is surjective). Let $R_V$ (also denoted $V^{\flat}$) the tilt of $V$, that is, the projective limit of $...\to V/pV\to V/pV$ where the maps are Frobenius. The elements $x$ of $R_V$ are identified to sequences $\{x^{(m)}\}_{m\geq 0}$ in $V$ such that $(x^{(m+1)})^p=x^{(m)}$ for all $m$ (the reduction mod $p$ of this sequence gives the sequence defining $x$ as element of the projective limit). Let $W(R_V)$ be the ring of Witt vectors and
$$W(R_V)\to V$$
the ring homomorphism sending $[x_0,x_1,x_2,...]$ to $\sum x_n^{(n)}p^n$, which defines a homomorphism of $\Lambda$-algebras
$$\theta :\Lambda\otimes_{\mathbb Z}W(R_V)\to V$$.

In "[Le corps des périodes p-adiques](http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_1994__223__59_0/)", Fontaine defines 
$${\rm A_{inf}}(V|\Lambda)$$
as the completion of $\Lambda\otimes_{\mathbb Z}W(R_V)$ for the $(p)+{\rm ker}(\theta)$-adic topology, and in remark 1.2.4.(b) he says that the canonical map
$${\rm A_{inf}}(V|\Lambda)\to {\rm A_{inf}}(V/pV|\Lambda)$$
is an isomorphism.

**Why?**

It is obvious that $R_V=R_{V/pV}$, but I am not able to prove that the completions are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Calling $\overline V:= V/pV$, there is a commutative diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\Lambda \otimes W(R_V) @>{\theta_1}>> V\\
@V\simeq ViV @VVV\\
\Lambda \otimes W(R_{\overline{V}}) @>{\theta_2}>> \overline V
\end{CD}

where the left vertical arrow is the isomorphism $i$ induced from the natural isomorphism $R_V \simeq R_{\overline{V}}$ you have, the right vertical arrow is the natural mod $p$ projection, and the horizontal maps are the $\theta$'s for constructing $A_{inf}(V\vert \Lambda)$ resp. $A_{inf}(\overline{V}\vert \Lambda)$.

From here, $i(ker(\theta_1) + (p)) = ker(\theta_2)+(p)$ and the claim is immediate.

Comment: Thank you. Why $ker(\theta_2 )\subset i(ker(\theta_1) + (p))$? This is the part that I am able to prove only in the particular case stated at the end of the question.

Comment: $\theta([x_0,x_1, ...])\in pV \Rightarrow x_0^{(0)}=0 \Rightarrow x_0=0 \Rightarrow [x_0,x_1, ...] \in pW(R_V)$.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking for more details, but I do not understand the second implication.Why $x_0^{(0)}=0$ implies $x_0=0$. Note that $\overline{V}$ is assumed only semiperfect, not perfect.

Comment: Thinking a little more, if $ker(\theta_2)\subset pW(R_V)$ via $i$ as you wrote, then $ker(\theta_1)\subset ker(\theta_2)\subset (p)$. Is it possible?

Comment: Indeed, the implication $x_0^{(0)} \Rightarrow x_0=0$ does not hold. But $x_0^{(0)}=0 \Rightarrow \theta([x_0,0,0,...])=0$ and further since $[x_0,x_1,...] = [x_0,0,0,...]+[0,x_1,x_2,...]$ (nontrivial but true in Witt vectors) we get $[x_0,x_1,...] \in ker(\theta) + (p)$, right?

Comment: In other words, $ker(\theta)+(p) = ker(pr \circ \theta)$ where $pr$ denotes projection mod $p$.

Comment: To make sure I have read you well, I'll add subscripts. I think you meant $x_0^{(0)}=0 \Rightarrow \theta_2([x_0,0,0,...])=0$ (if it is $\theta_1$ I do not know why it is true), so as you say in the last comment, this implies $ker(\theta_2)\subset ker(pr\circ \theta_1)$. Up to now, I understand all, in fact this last inclusion follows from the commutativity of the diagram, but I don't see how this solves my question. You also write $[x_0,x_1,...]\in ker(\theta_2)+(p)$. Again, if $\theta_2$ is correct I don't now how to apply this; if you meant $\theta_1$, I do not now why this inclusion holds.

Comment: I meant it holds for $\theta_1$, by the very definition of $\theta$, which sends $[x_0,0,...]$ to $\sum x_n^{(n)}p^n= x_0^{(0)}=0$. (Of course it also holds for $\theta_2$, but there we even have $(p) \subset ker(\theta_2)$ just because $\theta_2$ is a homomorphism.)

Comment: But from the original hypothesis $\theta_2([x_0,x_1,...])=0$ you deduce only that $x_0^{(0)}=0$ in $\overline{V}$, not in $V$, so $\theta_1([x_0,0,...])=x_0^{(0)}\in pV$. Why is it zero?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108679/discussion-between-torsten-schoeneberg-and-a-g).